# Decrement Variable by 1 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php include('railways.php')?>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<p>Enter trainid </p>
<input type="text" name="trainid"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$availableSeatsAC="";
$bookedSeatsAC = "";
$id = $_POST['trainid'];
$query = "UPDATE trainstatus SET ";
$query .= "availableSeatsAC = $availableSeatsAC-1, ";
$query .= "bookedSeatsAC = $bookedSeatsAC+1 ";
$query .= "WHERE trainid = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
if(!$result){
  die('QUERY FAILED'.mysqli_error($connection));
   }
   else{
    echo "CORRECTLY WORKED";

   }
}
?>
```

AvailableSeatsAC is set to 10 and bookedSeatsAC is set to 0 in the database. On providing the trainid and clicking the submit button the query runs.  It adds one to bookedSeatsAC making it 1 as expected but shows available seats to be -1 instead of 9. Any solution?

Comment: Remove both `$` signs in the query

Comment: $availableSeatsAC assigned to empty?

Comment: Use column names instead these variables.

Comment: This is a typographical error; voted as such.

Comment: Your code is also subject to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement if you value the time you put into this and your data.

Comment: Yes it was because of the dollar sign. Worked correctly after removing it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$id = $_POST['trainid'];
$query = "UPDATE trainstatus SET ";
$query .= "availableSeatsAC = availableSeatsAC-1, ";
$query .= "bookedSeatsAC = bookedSeatsAC+1 ";
$query .= "WHERE trainid = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
if(!$result){
  die('QUERY FAILED'.mysqli_error($connection));
   }
   else{
    echo "CORRECTLY WORKED";

   }
}
?>
```